# R: how to change the number of columns in each row in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Through ggplot, I have a plot like the following using the code below. But I cannot see the x-axis at all if I plot like this. I am wondering if there is any way to get around with that such as changing the number of columns in each row. I have tried `ncol` command in `facet_grid` but it does not allow me to do that.

```
ggplot(derivative, aes(x = factor(move), fill = factor(move)), colour = black)+ 
geom_bar()+
facet_grid(Market~Season)+
 scale_fill_discrete(name="Relative Market Move",
                  breaks=c("neg.big", "neg.small", "pos.big", "pos.small"),
                  labels=c("Big Negative", "Small Negative", "Big Positive", "Small Positive"))+
 scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Large Negative", "Small Negative", "large Positive", "Small Positive"))+
labs( x = "") +ylab("Count")
```

[image: cramped faceted plot]

Comment: You can't (AFAIK) set the number of columns with `facet_grid`. You could separately plot half the columns in one graph and half in another, but then you'll lose the ability to easily compare across a row. What about just displaying the graph with a wider aspect ratio and perhaps rotating the x-labels 90 degrees?

Comment: The grid is determined by the number of levels of the variables in the formula you pass, so without changing the setup, your best bet is to just make the aspect ratio wider when you save it as eipi10 said. Alternatives: **i** Drop the x-axis labels, as they're the same as your colors. **ii** Use `facet_wrap` and plan carefully. **iii** Since the horizontal facets are seasons anyway, make them your x-axis, and keep using color to make a grouped barplot faceted only by market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off with a stacked bar plot and with the bars for the "negatives" pointing downward. This will use horizontal space more efficiently and make it easier to see time trends. For example:

```
library(reshape2)
```

First create some fake data:

```
set.seed(199)
dat = data.frame(index=rep(c("S&P 500","Shanghai","Hang Seng"), each=7),
                 year=rep(paste0(rep(2009:2015,each=2),rep(c("Sp","Au"),7)), 3),
                 replicate(3, sample(50:100,14*3)))
dat$big.neg = 300 - rowSums(dat[,3:5])
names(dat)[3:5] = c("big.pos","small.pos","small.neg")

# Set year order
dat$year = factor(dat$year, levels=dat$year[1:14])

# Melt to long format
dat = melt(dat, id.var=c("year","index"))
```

Now for the plot:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=dat[dat$variable %in% c("big.pos","small.pos"),], 
           aes(x=year, y=value, fill=rev(variable)), stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data=dat[dat$variable %in% c("big.neg","small.neg"),], 
           aes(x=year, y=-value, fill=variable), stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="grey40") +
  facet_grid(index ~ .) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("big.neg","small.neg","small.pos","big.pos"),
                    values=c("red","blue","orange","green")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-200,200), breaks=seq(-200,200,100), 
                     labels=c(200,100,0,100,200)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  labs(fill="") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]